# Help using mod_jk to forward to backend app server

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk

I had mod-jk working a while ago but after switching servers and modifying some files, it no longer works.  I am using mod_jk-1.2.28 with JBoss 4.2.3 as the backend.

In the JBoss server.xml file I have the AJP 1.3 connector defined on port 8009 and I am binding jboss to the server's new IP address.  The app I am trying to forward to is deployed as:

```
[TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/ManualAlerts, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp8097651929280250028ManualAlertsApp.ear-contents/ManualAlerts-exp.war/
```

On the web server, I have worker.properties with a worker set for the JBoss address and port 8009.

The mod-jk.conf has JkMount /ManualAlerts/* worker1.

Shouldn't this forward all requests to the web server with the URL http://address/ManualAlerts/ to the backend app named ManualAlerts?

The mod-jk.log shows:

```
[Sat Oct 31 14:19:28 2009][30709:3086014224] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1507): (worker1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=115)
[Sat Oct 31 14:19:28 2009][30709:3086014224] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[Sat Oct 31 14:19:28 2009][30709:3086014224] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2466): (worker1) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Sat Oct 31 14:19:28 2009][30709:3086014224] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1384): service failed, worker worker1 is in error state
[Sat Oct 31 14:19:28 2009][30709:3086014224] [info] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1464): All tomcat instances are busy or in error state
[Sat Oct 31 14:19:28 2009][30709:3086014224] [error] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1469): All tomcat instances failed, no more workers left
```

Running `netstat -an` on the app server shows jboss listening on 8009 and the local address is the app server's address.  In the mod-jk.log it shows connect to (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8009) failed, and the app-server address is correct here, too.  I cannot figure out what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It msay be s good idea to post your mod-jk.conf, workers.properties and the ajp connection definition. Without them, I'd say you should try adding the following mount point:

```
JkMount /ManualAlerts worker1
```